# can i upload folder to dropbox without zipping it through android programatically?

Tags: android, directory, dropbox

I wanted to upload folder from my device to dropbox just like files. Can I do that without zipping?

I have done file uploading using dropbox api but cannot upload a directory.

I just zipped a directory and uploaded it, but I can't find a way to unzip directory on dropbox through android

please help me...

Comment: If you can upload files you can upload folders too provided you can create a folder at destination too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to upload each file individually. Enumerate the files in the local directory, and then loop over each one and upload.